# Цикл for в saas

Tags: css, sass, scss

```
  @for $i from 1 to 4 {
.social_proof_img{$i}{
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background: url(../images/social{$i}.png)no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Возможно ли такое в SCSS?

Comment: [нет](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for)

Comment: возможно; см: https://habr.com/ru/post/151679/